# Uncited references with internal bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I'm using an internal bibliography in my main .tex file :

```
\begin{thebibliography}{100}
```

Is there a way to tell which entries I'm not referencing so I can remove them? I'm using texshop, and except for a

```
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
```

it tells me nothing more specific (I think).

Comment: The `LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.` tells you that you either using `\ref`s without proper `\label`s or IIRC a wrong `\cite`.

Comment: Further up in the log file there will be more specific message telling you what references weren't defined.

Comment: did you run `latex`->`bibtex`->`latex` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, to find out uncited bibliography item, you can use

```
\usepackage[backref]{hyperref}
```

to enable back reference. Be sure that there is a blank line after each `\bibitem`. Then check the pdf file, you'll see uncited item clearly.

Test file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backref]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\cite{foo}

\begin{thebibliography}{ab}
\bibitem{foo} foo

\bibitem{bar} bar

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Second, for cross references, which is an independent question, there should be a waring like:

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `XXX' on page 123 undefined on input line 1234.
```

Comment: I think he is looking to find out which entries in the `thebibliography` environment are not cited, not which cites are not in the environment.

Comment: Ah, I missed it. There're two independent questions.

Comment: Sorry. I was not clear in my question. I was indeed looking for uncited references which was answered by @Leo. The error message I was pointing out has nothing to do with this, and the cross reference problem was not my present issue.